# Frobenius Norm Properties

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Say $v\in {\mathbb{R}^{l}}$ (a column vector) and $A\in {\mathbb{R}^{l\times l}}$. I have encountered the following equality:

$||v{{v}^{T}}-A||_{F}^{2}={{\left( {{v}^{T}}v \right)}^{2}}-2{{v}^{T}}Av+tr(A^2)$.

where tr() denotes the trace of a matrix and $||\cdot||_F$ the Frobenius norm. It doesn't seem correct though. It'll be great if someone provides the intermediate steps leading to the right side of the equation.

edit: $tr(A)$ -> $tr(A^2)$. The equality is taken from a conference paper, so I assume its correct.

Comment: I dont get, you think it isn't correct but yet want the intermediate steps? Doens't make sense.

Comment: The $\mathrm{tr}(A)$ on the right should read $\mathrm{tr}(A^\top A)$.

Comment: So is it correct? It doesn't appear correct to me, but the equality was taken from an optimization article so I assume its correct, hence my desire to see the intermediate steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write down the equation in coordinates and you can see it easily
$$ \sum_{ij}(v_iv_j-a_{ij})^2 =\sum_{ij} (v_iv_jv_jv_i  -2 v_ia_{ij}v_j - a_{ij}a_{ij} ) = (v^Tv)^2- 2v^TAv + tr(A^TA)$$